# Matlab: Turn a part of a text file into a matrix

Tags: matlab

The file need to import looks like this:

```
 MASS INFORMATION:
  TOTAL MASS =  12197.    
  CENTROID (X,Y,Z) =  30.000      0.0000      8.5809    
  MOMENT OF INTERTIA ABOUT ORIGIN:
    IXX = 0.10651E+07    IYY = 0.18383E+08    IZZ = 0.17318E+08
    IXY =  0.0000        IYZ =  0.0000        IZX =-0.31397E+07

 ROW     1 MATRIX     1
   0.69366833E+09  0.12654965E+09   0.0000000     -0.22831656E+09   0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
  -0.20667723E+09   0.0000000       0.0000000     -0.24801268E+09 -0.24549730E-05
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
  -0.48699110E+09 -0.12654965E+09   0.0000000       19696122.       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    

 ROW     1 MATRIX     2
    946.16939       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    93.879840       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    349.12106       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    

 ROW     2 MATRIX     1
   0.12654965E+09  0.26613603E+10   0.0000000      -73506929.       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000     -0.26127500E+10   0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
  -0.12654965E+09  -48610261.       0.0000000      -73506929.       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    

 ROW     2 MATRIX     2
    0.0000000       946.16939       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       93.879840       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       349.12106       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000
```

That is, everyline of the `Matrix 1` and `Matrix 2` is contained in this file.
But due to the ill-format of the text file, it is impossile to turn it into a matrix and then to import data.

I want:
1. locate the every `ROW X MATRIX 1`
2. Turn the next `N` lines into a matrix so we can read its data easily. Specifically, I need the 1st and 2nd column. So I turn the first 2 column into a new matrix and then loop through it and turn it into one line.

So, How can I turn the data below the `ROW X MATRIX 1` into a matrix?

UPDATE:
expected output, let's say I just want the `ROW 1 MATRIX 2`:

```
 row2_matrix1=
   0.12654965E+09  0.26613603E+10   0.0000000      -73506929.       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000     -0.26127500E+10   0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
  -0.12654965E+09  -48610261.       0.0000000      -73506929.       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000    
    0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000
```

The above is a NXN matrix.
So later I can manipulate the date within this matrix with ease.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you care about everything in this data file, but more about those tables. All you need to do is to skip lines until your next line contains row 1 and read everything until the end. [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) guide has probably something that you will be interested in. Also, you might want to preserve the row and matrix numbers when reading the line. string parsing and splitting can help you do that.

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: So you for the given text file it would output four matrices?

Comment: Well...I may not be clear enough. I edit it again. So, How can I turn the `ROW     2 MATRIX     1` into a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
fid = fopen(inputfile); %// Edit inputfile to the path of your text file
tline = fgetl(fid);
num_array = [];
while ischar(tline)    
    if ~isempty(tline)
        tline_valid = strtrim(tline);
        if isstrprop(tline_valid(1),'digit') || tline_valid(1)=='-'
            num_array{end+1} = tline_valid; %#ok<SAGROW>
        end
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);

cell_data = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x), num_array,'un',0)
out_allcols = str2double(vertcat(cell_data{:}))
out = out_allcols(:,1:2)
```

Comment: Make sure to use `format long g` to see the outputs as the values in `out` seem to vary between `E10s` to `100s`.

Comment: How do you locate the `ROW X MATRIX 1`? I didn't see this in code at all.

Comment: @cqcn1991 I am locating the digits - `0 to 9` and `-` to detect lines that start with numbers. Isn't that a good assumption for your input text file?

Comment: Then you can't distinguis between `Matrix 1`, and `Matrix 2'. There 2 different matrix. (And each row of them is turn into a submatrix here.) That's why the header is written as 'Row X Matirx X'.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Can you update the question with the expected output?

Comment: I've updated. I just want something like `turn_matrix(start_line_number, end_line_number)`, and then out put the needed matrix. Line number are easy to get, but I have no idea of turning it into matrix.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Please edit with all the expected matrices for the given input text file? Also, please give them unique names? Because you have given them the same names, which is sort of confusing.

Comment: My fault, I forget to change their names. We don't need to get all the matrices here. I just want give a `start_line_number` and a `end_line_number`, and output this matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64382/discussion-between-cqcn1991-and-divakar).

Comment: @cqcn1991 there's some question(s) for you in chat.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Do all matrices have the same number of rows? If so, what is that number?

Comment: Yes, it's a 11X5 matrix, as you can see in the example. `ROW     1 MATRIX     2` is could be any title.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Do this `N = 11, out1 = permute(reshape(out_allcols,N,size(out_allcols,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2])`. This would give you a 3D array. Thus, `out(:,:,1)` would be `ROW     1 MATRIX     1`,`out(:,:,2)` would be `ROW     1 MATRIX     2`, `out(:,:,3)` would be `ROW     2 MATRIX     1`,`out(:,:,4)` would be `ROW     2 MATRIX     2`. Makes sense now?

Comment: @cqcn1991 Just curious - Did that update work for you?

Comment: Yes, I finally made it by myself. Thank you.